# Get the user to enter a name but using file stream *fp

Tags: c

I am a beginner in c so I have a problem with get the user to input last name, a comma & then first name. However it will pass to the function call

**int get_name(FILE *fp)**

in my main function. I have a problem either if I have to use the arguments parameters.

**Example, main (int argc, char *argv[])) or just main (void))**

and from what I have been searching so far, **FILE*fp** cannot get the user to enter from stdin it only use to open the file(?) BUT I am required to get the user to input from keyboard and pass to the function. I have written some codes. but they don't seem to work but I am going to put down on here the one I am sure that I need a few changes most.

```
#define LINESIZE1024

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    char line[LINESIZE];
    char first;
    char last;
    char comma;
    while(1){
            if(!fgets(line,LINESIZE,stdin)){
                clearerr(stdin);
                break;
            }
            if(fp = (sscanf(line,"%s %s %s",&last,&comma,&first)==3))
                get_name(fp);
                if(get_last_first(fp)== -1)
                    break;
            printf("Please enter first name a comma and then last name");

        }
```

BUT I got an error saying I can't use pass it from pointer to an integer. and many MORE but I accidentally closed my concolse and all the errors that appeared while I was trying to fix are gone. So please give me some ideas.

What about seconde code

```
while(1){
            if(!fgets(line,LINESIZE,fp)){
                clearerr(stdin);
                break;
            }
            if(sscanf(line,"%s %s %s",last,comma,first)==3)
                get_last_first(fp);

    return 0;
    }
```

It gave me errors too. fp,last,first,comma used uninitialized in this function

OK so I think I have fixed the previous problem now. However it doesn't print the name back if the name is given correctly. Here is my fixed main code.

```
int main(void){
    FILE *fp = stdin;
    char line[LINESIZE];
    char first[16];
    char last[16];

    while(1){
            if(!fgets(line,LINESIZE,stdin)){
                clearerr(stdin);
                break;
            }
            if(sscanf(line,"%s ,%s",last,first)==2)
                if(get_name(fp)==2)
                    printf("Your name is: %s %s\n", first, last);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

here is my function.

```
int get_name(FILE *fp){

    char line[LINESIZE];
    char last[16], first[16];
    int  n;

/* returns -1 if the input is not in the correct format
            or the name is not valid */
        if(fgets(line, LINESIZE, fp) == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        /* returns 0 on EOF */
        if((n = sscanf(line, " %[a-zA-Z-] , %[a-zA-Z-]", last, first)) == EOF) {
            return 0;
        }
        /* prints the name if it's valid */
        if((n = sscanf(line, " %[a-zA-Z-] , %[a-zA-Z-]", last, first)) == 2) {
            return 2;
        }
    return 1;
}
```

I thank you people so much for taking time to read and help me. Please don't be mean :)

Comment: The expression `(sscanf(line,"%s %s %s",&last,&comma,&first)==3)` does not return a `FILE*`. You should enable warnings.

Comment: Do you want to store the entered name in a text file?

Comment: @GauravPathak no. I don't want to. My instructor said that "Use stdin as FILE * when testing -- you do not need to open any files." so I am so confused as how to get the user input and pass it as *fp.

Comment: You ned to write the function `int get_name(FILE *fp) { .... }` When writing the function, you don't need to care whether `fp` is `stdin` or a real file. Just use `fgets(line,LINESIZE,fp)` to read from it and then process the line read. In `main` you call it like `get_name(stdin);`

Comment: Don't do `fgets` and `sscanf` in `main`. Only call them inside the function.

Comment: @4386427 what do I have to use instead of those two then? that's the only way for me to get fp pointer pass to another function.

Comment: " I accidentally closed my concolse and all the errors that appeared while I was trying to fix are gone" - and you deleted all tools, so you can't try again … yeah, that always happens on errors.

Comment: @Olaf ok if you are not here to take minutes to help but rather being salty. Please leave or ask me nicely. However I posted edited codes that partially work now. (if you read until the end)

Comment: @Olaf it costs $0 to be nice :) thank you and good night.

Comment: @dyingStudent: 1) It is not your's to tell people not to comment. Being caught with a lame excuse for being lazy and being told that is no offence and not unpolite. 2) Wasting other's time to debug one's code very well is. 3) Read [ask] and follow site rules. 4) We don't have $. You are not the centre of the world.

Comment: @Olaf I don't see how my post or comments indicate that I think the world revolves around me. Also, I have read documentations and follow guidelines. I am not supposed to delete the non-working code so I kept updating my new working code. You just did not read until the end. Please read the post until the end before you think I am being lazy. Comments like yours are very discouraging. Not so nice :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to read from the keyboard, read from `stdin` or use `scanf`, which internally reads from `stdin`. If you want to read from a file instead, use `FILE *fp`, but don't forget to open the file and check if it was successful (you'll find lots of tutorials for this).

Further, when reading in strings, you need an array of characters, not a single one. Note further, that `scanf` can already deal with formats like "everything that is not a ',' then a ','  then a string. Note that format `"[^,]"` means "any character except a ',':

So you could adapt the code as follows:

```
#define LINESIZE 1024
int main(void){
    char line[LINESIZE];
    char first[LINESIZE];
    char last[LINESIZE];
    while(fgets(line,LINESIZE,stdin)) {
        if(sscanf(line,"%[^,],%s",last,first)==2) {
            printf("Read in %s ... %s\n",last,first);
        }
        else {
            printf("Please enter first name a comma and then last name");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And if your professor is picky concerning the "use FILE*", you could write:

```
FILE *fp = stdin;
...
while(fgets(line,LINESIZE,fp)) {
   ...
```

Comment: hello but I am given the function prototype int get_name(FILE *fp) I am not asked to open the file or anything.

Comment: yes! I used that now too! and I think it works. How ever it doesn't print the name back. I will post my code for the function. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are making it more complicated than needed. Don't call `fgets` and `scanf` in `main`. Only do that in the function `get_name`.

It can be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINESIZE 1024

int get_name(FILE *fp)
{
    char line[LINESIZE];
    char* t;

    if(!fgets(line, LINESIZE,fp))
    {
        printf("Error reading input\n");
        return 0;
    }

    t = strstr(line, ",");
    if (t)
    {
        *t = '\0';
        ++t;
        printf("First: %s -  Last: %s\n", line, t);
        return 2;
    }

    printf("Illegal input\n");
    return 0;
}

int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    get_name(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

If you later decide that you want to read from a file, you can reuse the function `get_name` without changing it at all. All you need is to change `main`. Like:

```
int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE* f = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (f)
    {
        get_name(f);
        fclose(f);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Open file failed\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: oh I am sorry! there was a comment up there and I was confused that person with you. Thank you again!!!! you helped a lot.

Comment: @dyingStudent - ok - I see. Let's delete the comments.